# Cross Page Postback and passing info from source to destination page

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a `FileUpload` control in the Source page. On the Upload button handler, I read the file into memory (after doing some validations) and since it's always going to be a TXT file, I create a string that I need to pass to the Destination page.

I thought of using Cross Page postback and set the `PostBackUrl` property of the upload button. But it appears that the breakpoint in the Upload button handler is never hit. It directly goes to the `Page_Load` in the Destination page.

If I can't use Cross Page postback and don't want to use Session or the database, how do I pass this string from Source page to the Destination page?

Anyone?

Comment: it will always do a Page_Load first of all and after that any event handlers are called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Session

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTPContext object to do this. Just add your values to context like this

```
Context.Items["Myvariable"] = "myValue";
```

See The **[HttpContext Items Collection](http://odetocode.com/Articles/111.aspx)**

Comment: With the HTTPContext object, I can pass data between pages?

Comment: Well, I need to use Server.Transfer with a Context object. I would like to do a Response.Redirect.