# How to make PostBack from one page to another and pass parameters?

Tags: .net, post, parameters, postback

I need to make PostBack from source page to destination page. Destination page expects several parameters to be past to it. (I don't have control over destination, I just know what parameters are expected).

For example destination page expects 3 parameters:
**param1

param2

param3**

My source page has controls with ids param1, param2 and param3, but because I am using master pages my controls get altered to:
**ctl00$param1

ctl00$param2

ctl00$param3**

So when I do PostBack destination page doesn't receive parameters it expects. How do I get around that?

What is proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post to another page using Server.Transfer with

HttpContext.Current.Items["CustomerName"] = "Fred";

The following post outlines your option(s). 
[Cross Page Postback and passing info from source to destination page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264141/cross-page-postback-and-passing-info-from-source-to-destination-page)

more info about HttpContext Items:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx